# High Memory usage of Content Deployer and Content Discovery services

Tags: content-delivery, web8, deployer, discovery-service

Hello I have noticed that Deployer and Discovery Services consume a lot of memory,

There are any way to optimize these services?

In the next picture you can see a low consume of RAM only with Content Manager Service Host and SQL Server services started. After start Content Deployer and Content Discovery services, RAM comsuption soars.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using the default service configurations? Is this graph in-use or running idle?

You can try reducing the maximum memory used by the Discovery Service down to 128Mb (see the `bin/install.ps1` or `install.sh` script for the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` settings). Try setting them to: `"-Xms64m", "-Xmx128m"`

The deployer can be adjusted dependent on the size of transport packages that you are typically sending. If they are small, the deployer service memory footprint could also be reduced.

Comment: See docs for additional reference: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-882178AA-A7E5-451B-8CD3-9F06D967F9BE

Comment: This graph is running idle. I installed the default deployer(standalone). In others installations I noticed that tomcat running as service on windows spend a lot of Memory, I read in SDL documentation that this REST service create a Tomcat instance.... I will try to reduce the Java_opts. Thanks!

Comment: Do see you see any unusual logging in either the Discovery or Deployer service logs?

Comment: Yes indeed - the standalone services use individual instances of Tomcat under the covers to run each micro service.